# Conditionals with char, int and vector C++

Tags: c++

So, I have been working on a simple program that when given an array of letters that are only comprised of r and b it will iterate through that array and count the number of each letter.

However, the program runs ok, but outputs 0, 0.

Please Help!

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int main() {



int red = 0;
int blue = 0;


vector <int> necklace;
int beads;

while (cin >> beads){
    necklace.push_back(beads);
}

for(beads = 0; beads < necklace.size(); beads++){
    if( beads == 'r' ){
       red++;
    }
    else if( beads == 'b'){
        blue++;
    }

}

cout << red  << endl << blue << endl ;

}
```

Comment: What is the input you are giving the program? What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: What according to you is `while (cin >> beads)` doing?

Comment: Also `beads` is an `int` variable but apparently you are inputting `r` and `b` into it since you are checking `if( beads == 'r' )`!

Comment: `while (cin >> beads)` won't ring true if you try inputting a non numeric set.

Comment: Also how would `beads` be ever equal to `r` or `b` when you yourself have initialized `beads` to 0 and are then incrementing it i.e. it would always take integer values.

Comment: @AditiRawat It's possible for `beads` to be "equal" to `r` or `b` if the `vector` grows to a size equal to the decimal value of `r`+1 or `b`+1 with whatever character set the op is using.

Comment: @George yes seems possible

Comment: Thanks to everyone who replied. I managed to solve it, you can see how I did it in my comment to Rinkesh.

Answer (score 0):

In your program beads is an integer.
You are adding integer to your necklace vector. So it doesn't go inside your if condition as beads should be 'r' or 'b' but it is some number.

Comment: Comparing char to int is not illegal. But here it doesn't serve the purpose. As Ben wants to check for 'r' and 'b', not for numbers.

Comment: I actually figured it out, what i ended up doing was comparing necklace[beads] to 'r' and 'b' it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change, a bit of Your program. First change `int` to `char`, also change way (loop) of getting signs/chars from input. Second You have to fix checking if there is 'r' or 'b' in the vector. You have to use table operator '[]'.
Here is fixed version of Your program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int red = 0, blue = 0;

    vector <char> necklace;
    char beads;
    string line;

    getline(cin, line);
    istringstream iss(line);

    while (iss >> beads)
    {
        necklace.push_back(beads);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < necklace.size(); i++)
    {
        beads = necklace[i];
        if (beads == 'r' )
        {
            red++;
        }
        else if(beads == 'b')
        {
            blue++;
        }
    }

    cout << red  << endl << blue << endl ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Armo, i managed to fix it independent of your advice, but I did something similar to what you said here.